# Integrating the square root of a quartic

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to determine a reduction formula for an integral of the following form
$$\int \sqrt{ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e}\:\mathrm{d}x$$
I'm not sure if it is even solvable. I was wondering if you guys could help. Also, I was interested as to if there was a way to determine if a given integral is even evaluable. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Did you ever encountered the [elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral); because you going to need them here!

Comment: @mrtaurho Thank you! I have not seen those before. I will look into them!

Comment: It's worth imposing $x^\prime=x+\frac{b}{4a}$ to delete the cubic term, then taking out the $\sqrt{a}$ factor to remove one more degree of freedom. So with some relabelling, you only want $\int\sqrt{x^4+ax^2+bx+c}\:\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: @mrtaurho Sorry to bother you, but I tried looking into elliptic integrals, but hit a dead end. Obviously my integrand is of the form $R(t, \sqrt{P(t)})$, but that's as far as I got. Could you give me a push in the right direction?